# Org-mode from git, problems with tables

Tags: emacs, org-mode, tabular

Recently I downloaded the git version of **org-mode** in order to use markdown export. It seems to be working, unless I have a table. When I have a table in the file I always got the next message:

> Symbol's function definition is void: org-table-begin

I also get that message when I want to use the table, like the **tab key** to navigate or whatsoever.

My configuration is pretty simple:

```
;; put in the load-path the org-mode directory
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/org-mode/lisp")
;; Activating the markdown export mode
(eval-after-load "org"
    '(require 'ox-md nil t)
)
```

Do you have any idea? I have the latest version of the git repository master.

Comment: What's your version of Emacs? You may need to `(require 'org-compat)`.

Comment: the version is 24.3.1

Comment: @Chris I tried ``(require 'org-compat)`` but I get the same error

Comment: How did you install Org-mode? You shouldn't need a development release for Markdown export; the latest version from the [Org ELPA](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) should work just fine.

Comment: Well, that's the way I found. Anyway, I solved the issue, It was so silly. I just needed to make again the source, because I ``git pull`` but the binaries were not created. :/ Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly answer for a silly question. I was using the org-mode repositories. I `git pull` the sources but I forgot to run `make` in order to generate the files. I just did `make` and that solved my problem.